# Phonon-phonon-interaction as higher order terms in the potential

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

Is there a simple way to understand why phonon-phonon-interaction is described by higher order terms in the potential?

I mean: Having a quadratic potential is essential for the definition of the phonons as excitations of an harmonic oscillator. How can you suddenly talk about (interacting) phonons when you don't have a simple quadratic potential anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, why are there no phonon-phonon interactions with a quadratic potential? A quadratic potential means Hook's Law; force is proportional to displacement. That [leads to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#From_Hooke.27s_law%22leads%20to%22) a nice linear wave equation. That allows for [superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle); waves just add together linearly and don't disturb each other. This all breaks down for non-linear wave equations -- ones that do not come from quadratic potentials.

This also holds for phonons, so it may be helpful to dig into the above material if you want to know more.

> How can you suddenly talk about (interacting) phonons when you don't have a simple quadratic potential anymore...

It's the same reason we say springs following Hooke's law or pendulums with small oscillations are simple harmonic oscillators; neither is true, but they're mostly right and form a good starting point.

We use good, old-fashioned time-dependent perturbation theory. The quadratic potential  $H_0$ is mostly right; the higher order terms $H_p$ (the perturbing Hamiltonian) are small compared to the quadratic term. Together:

$$H=H_0+H_p$$

You already have a complete set of solutions for the quadratic potential, so you use them along with the perturbing Hamiltonian and Fermi's Golden Rule. The rate of transition from state $\left|a\right\rangle$ to $\left|b\right\rangle$ is then:

$$R_{b\to a}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\left|\langle a|H_p|b\rangle\right|^2\rho$$

where $\rho$ is the density of states. Those transitions are phonon-phonon scattering.

$H_p$ has other effects too; e.g. it'll change the energy levels a little. However, that's usually neglected because it has much less important than the  phonon-phonon scattering this perturbation brings. You'll need to break out a mid-level quantum book if you want more details.

Why time dependent (rather than independent) perturbation theory? That's a tougher question. If you want to dig into it, it might be useful to start with some of van Hove's articles:

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0031-8914(54)92646-4

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0031-8914(57)92891-4

The short version is that it works, and that it's never wrong to treat things as time dependent, even if they're not.

Comment: $H=H_0+H_p$, right? Nice and simple answer anyways!

Comment: Yup. I'll fix the typo.